# User shared GEOlocation does not work with google places

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, google-places-api, google-places

I don't know how to search for this in SO, so I'm asking a new question. What could cause or what is the concrete problem of my code: HTML generated by Javascript (`createElement()` and `appendChild`) is not being shown in Opera and Firefox, but it works in Chromium.

The HTML generating code:

```
function typesOfPlaces(map, bounds) {
  var allowedTypes = [
    "amusement_park",
    "aquarium",
    "art_gallery",
    "cemetery",
    "church",
    "city_hall",
    "hindu_temple",
    "mosque",
    "museum",
    "night_club",
    "park",
    "place_of_worship",
    "rv_park",
    "spa",
    "synagogue",
    "travel_agency",
    "zoo"
  ];
  var typesToDisplay = new Array();
  var request =  {
    bounds: bounds,
    types: allowedTypes
  };
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < results[i].types.length; j++) {
          for(var k = 0; k < allowedTypes.length; k++) {
            if(results[i].types[j] == allowedTypes[k]) {
              var allowed = true;
              for(var x = 0; x < typesToDisplay.length; x++) {
                if(allowedTypes[k]==typesToDisplay[x]) {
                  allowed = false;
                }
              }
              if(allowed) {
                typesToDisplay.push(allowedTypes[k]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      var parent = document.getElementById("types");
      for(var i = 0; i < typesToDisplay.length; i++) {
        var typeBox = document.createElement("div");
        var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
        var checkID = randomString(10);
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkBox.setAttribute("id", checkID);
        label.setAttribute("for", checkID);
        label.innerHTML = typesToDisplay[i];
        typeBox.appendChild(checkBox);
        typeBox.appendChild(label);
        parent.appendChild(typeBox);
      }
    }
  });
}//END OF Function
```

**UPDATE TO COMMENTS**

The randomString is just SO'ed code for generating random string:

```
function randomString(L) {
  var s= '';
  var randomchar=function() {
    var n= Math.floor(Math.random()*62);
    if(n<10) return n; //1-10
    if(n<36) return String.fromCharCode(n+55); //A-Z
    return String.fromCharCode(n+61); //a-z
  }
  while(s.length< L) s+= randomchar();
  return s;
}
```

div #types really exists, it look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=lt"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="types"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the import of google.maps.places.PlacesService by looking at the `<head>` section of the `<script>` tag, where you can see "&libraries=places".

**SECOND UPDATE AFTER SOME TESTING**

ok. I've figured out that if I deny location sharing in opera it works (it works in chromium because by default it does not even ask user if he is kind to share his geolocation with website)

The code for geolocation:

```
function initGeo()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
    else
    {
        errorFunction();
    }
}
```

so, the function that does not work is successFunction (which is being launched if user kindly shares his geolocation)

```
function successFunction(position)
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var abstract_location;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            abstract_location = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(), 
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast());
        }
        else
        {
            alert("NOT SUCCESS 1");
        }
        showGMap(latlng, abstract_location);
    });
}
```

And the errorFunction, which successfully works on chromium by default and on Opera if you deny access to your geolocation:

```
function errorFunction(error)
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude, google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                var abstract_location = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(), 
                    results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast());
            }
            else
            {
                alert("NOT SUCCESS 2");
            }
            showGMap(latlng, abstract_location);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': 'Vilnius Region, Lithuania'}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                var abstract_location = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(), 
                    results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast());
                showGMap(latlng, abstract_location);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("NOT SUCCESS 3");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Nor Chromium nor Opera does not give me ANY errors, nor javascript exceptionaly, nor in general.

So the problem is in success function. Because it even does not give me alert(typesToDisplay.length) [as suggested by Stuart in the comments] - it means that there is no alert at all - in case of error function I get the aswer 4 and thus i can see my generated HTML.

In case of success function there is just empty (without any appended childs) #types .

I do not see what could be causing success function to be NOTSUCCESS (:))

Comment: `randomString` is not defined in my browser. Where did you get it? Note that if `randomString` is not defined, nothing gets attached to the document.

Comment: why don't you use jQuery? It really simplifies DOM manipulation.

Comment: Look at the `Array().indexOf` function. It could replace a level or two in your pyramid.

Comment: We can only guess that the element `#types` really exists and can contain `div`s.

Comment: What about `google.maps.places.PlacesService`? Is it definitely imported?

Comment: a) Jan Dvorak, i have updated my post by answering your questions. b)I will look into array().indexOf c)I do not use jQuery, because i do not need and i do not want (do not want to include if i do not need all of it)

Comment: Does anything appear in the DOM that just fails to be rendered, or there's nothing there either? Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: @JanDvorak , you might be surprised, but there **are** people, who are smart enough to understand, how bad jQuery actually is.

Comment: can you check that typesToDisplay actually contains anything by inserting something like `alert(typesToDisplay.length);` above the line `var parent...`? The 2nd part of the code (from `var parent...` onwards) works for me in Firefox so the problem may be in the part that gets the information from the google service.

Comment: Extracting just the DOM code from your question seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/h4cRb/ Can you make a jsFiddle of the whole thing (integrating it with google maps)?

Comment: @tereško tell me, what's so bad about jQuery? Performance?

Comment: Ok, so i updated again, maybe you could see what i can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have figured it out - it was pretty simple though...

The Geolocation data which you get is an address, so bounds are very small, you have to extract city with reverse geocoding (results[6].formatted_address) and then you geocode that reverse geocode (so confused though Geocoding -> reverse -> again geocode) and then it works!

So the problem was at geocoding (haven't thought that bounds of address is not the whole city (that should have been obvious in the first place, but was not).

HTML5 geocoding could have the info about the city (not only lan and lng, firefox has something, but that's only firefox, not the whole HTML5), but i do not know if it would be good or not (lack of my personal knowlede at the moment in this specific field)

So if anyone does get to something similar -> **check the bounds** ;)

**Thank you** for your comments and for your view's.